# In perforce (PV4) how do I see all the check-in comments for a file including comment on other branches that have been merged in?

Tags: perforce

I wish to see the comments on all check-ins (change list) that has effected a file, including any check-ins to a different branch of the file that has since been merged in.

(Ideally I would like to filter out any comments if the only operation they relate to is a branch or none conflicting integration.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the History tab, there is a button that allows you to display branch actions.

[image: Perforce branch action display menu]

I don't know of any way to filter out submissions that were simply a branching operation.

Comment: I tried that but it did not show any history from before my branch was created.

Comment: @Ian: What version of the Perforce Server software are you using?  As I recall, this functionality was added in just the last few years.  Perhaps your version doesn't support it?

Comment: @Ian Ringrose, try to see what you can expand in the history view. By default, it collapses the history before a branch, but you should be able to expand one of the entries.

Comment: We are using a very old version of the perforce server, due to the cost of surport, hence this does not work for us.